# When would someone choose to use a limit string (<<-) instead of format here strings the normal way with <<<?

Tags: here-document, here-string

`The - option to mark a here document limit string (<<-LimitString) will suppress leading tabs (but not spaces) in the output.`

What I'm wondering is why someone would want to remove the leading tabs when they are processing commands with the "here" method. Is it about readability of output, or cleaning up output if we want to pass it to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about readability of the source code. With `<<-`, you can write:

```
foo() {
    cat <<-EOF
        hello
        EOF
    echo do something else
}
```

instead of

```
foo() {
    cat <<-EOF
hello
EOF
    echo do something else
}
```

giving a more logical indentation.

(Note that SE displays tabs as spaces in the rendered view of the post, so you'll have to imagine the blocks of four spaces there are tabs instead. Or copy and paste [from the source view](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/8aeba950-8cc5-49e7-9acc-1368160cbedf/view-source), if you like; it should give the contents with less mangling.)

I think the phrase "limit string" refers to the end delimiter of the here-doc, a thing you always have with one. It's the processing of the tabs that the additional `-` changes. Also, `<<<` is the non-standard here-string, not a here-doc.

.

Comment: So i'm guessing that << is the standard way to do here string then?

Comment: What is "standard"?  If you are using bash, `<<-` works as well as `<<`.

Comment: @user10489, the standard being the [POSIX shell command language specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). I never said `<<-` wasn't standard, just that `<<<` isn't.

Comment: @thinksinbinary, no, `<<` starts a here-doc, as does `<<-`, just with the special treatment of tabs. Both are standard. `<<<` is the here-string operator, in shells that support it. It's not standard. Isn't that what I just wrote in the answer?

Comment: Actually what you said, in answering whether << is the standard way to do a here string, was "Also, <<< is the non-standard here-string, not a here-doc." The intention was to clarify if << specifically was the standard here string, but you have answered so no need to say anymore if it's a problem for you.

Comment: @thinksinbinary, no, `<<` is not a here-string, but a here-doc. `<<<` is for a here-string, not a here-doc. Those are two different concepts, one of them is standard, the other isn't. See here, and the next one down https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents (not that Bash's manual tells which features are POSIX and which aren't, but e.g. Dash and Busybox don't support here-strings.)